# Unable to test the REST API developed with Spring Boot

Tags: rest, post, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I am trying to test the REST API created with Spring Boot. Following is the signature of the method:

```
@RequestMapping(consumes = "multipart/form-data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Response<String> upload(@RequestBody CsvUploadModel form) {
```

Following is the details of Model Object:

```
private char separator;
    private char quoteCharacter;
    private String metricName;
    private String groupName;
    private MultipartFile file;
//getters and setters
```

I have tried accessing this service using 1. chrome Postman and 2. Simple http POST form. Every time I am getting the error: 415 : Unsupported media type.

EDIT:
Following is the bean configuration for multi part bean:

```
/**
     * Allow file uploads
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultiPartConfigFactory factory = new MultiPartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize("500MB");
        factory.setMaxRequestSize("500MB");
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }

    /**
     * Get the multipart resolver
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }
```

I tried changing @RequestBody to @RequestParam but it didn't work. Following is the request preview of postman.

```
POST /dev/wizard/upload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:10022
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metricName"

test
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="separator"

,
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

Am I missing anything obvious?

Thanks

Comment: are you using embedded Tomcat? Are you creating a MultipartConfigElement bean?

Comment: I am using embedded Jetty. Yes, I am creating the MultiPartConfigElementBean. I have added the same in the question.

Comment: If I were you, I'd split out the MultipartFile from your model object and try passing it again as @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file.

Comment: `@RequestBody` body is used when the request contains a marshalled content like with json or xml. If you want to use plain binding use `@ModelAttribute`. `@RequestParam` is for binding plain request parameters. So basically your controllers method is wrongly defined or you are testing in the wrong way. Multipart file upload is enabled by default when using Spring Boot. To configure it use the `multipart.*` properties. See the [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration).

Comment: Managed to make it work by removing @RequestBody annotation. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RequestBody CsvUploadModel form
```

This requires a `HttpMessageConverter` to be present that can read request payloads of the type `multipart/form-data`. Unfortunately Spring currently does not provide such a converter. There is a `FormHttpMessageConverter`, but that can only read simple form data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

In order to get your method working you should remove the `@RequestBody` annotation and add a parameter for the files:

```
upload(CsvUploadModel form, @RequestParameter(required=false) MultipartFile file)
```

`@RequestBody` is not needed for binding form data. You then have to set the file manually:

```
form.setFile(file);
```

Maybe there's a third-party converter that supports reading `multipart/form-data`. Neither do I use nor know any.

Answer (score 0):

Try retrofit

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit</groupId>
     <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
     <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

.

```
 import retrofit.http.Body;
 import retrofit.http.POST;

 public interface IRestController {

      @POST("/api-name")
      public Response api(@Body Request request);
 }
```

.

```
 import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
 import org.junit.Test;
 import retrofit.RestAdapter;

 public class TestRestAPI {

       private static final String SERVER = "http://localhost:8080";

       private IRestController service = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                                            .setEndpoint(SERVER).build()
                                            .create(IRestController.class);

       @Test
       public void basicTest(){      
               Response response = service.api(new Request());
               assertNotNull(response);
       }
 }
```